# D-Link DWL-G510 rt61 card not recognized

Tags: 11.10, wireless, ralink

I need help here. I just install ubuntu desktop 11.10 and can't get my wireless card work. it is based on RALink chipset.

I've found a link pointing to a driver: http://suporte.dlink.com.br/suporte/index.php. but it seems that this driver doesn't include data for a kernel 3.x compilation, only 2.4 and 2.6 :(

can somebody help me?

EDITED:

After have removed and reinstalled the card into the machine, Ubuntu starts to recognize the card as a RALink at least. But RT61pci default driver didn't work. The network get the status of UNCLAIMED:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:03:02.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=32
   resources: memory:d0500000-d0507fff
```

So after have tried dozen of times to build the linux driver from DLink support site, I gave up and have tried with Ndiswrapper.

I discover that I need to use a 64bit driver and the only one that worked was the XP64 that I found [here](http://suporte.dlink.com.br/suporte/index.php).

Now its getting better because I can see more things with iwconfig:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:"dlink"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:20 dBm   Sensitivity=-121 dBm  
      RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B   
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

but I still can't connect to AP :(

lspci -nnk:

```
03:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g [1814:0302]
Subsystem: D-Link System Inc AirPlus G DWL-G510 Wireless Network Adapter (Rev.C) [1186:3c09]
Kernel driver in use: ndiswrapper
Kernel modules: rt61pci
```

rfkill list all :

```
returns nothing.
```

sudo lshw -class network :

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:03:02.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ndiswrapper+netrt61g driverversion=1.56+D-Link,06/12/2009, 1.02.08. latency=32 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11g
   resources: irq:21 memory:d0500000-d0507fff
```

Comment: @fossfreedom, I've updated with your info. thanks

Comment: hmmm - that's very strange - it should be recognised right out of the box.  Is this a firmware issue?  what is the output of `dmesg | grep -i firmware` or possibly `dmesg | grep -i phy` - there should be something in the kernel logs showing what happens when its loading the network.

Comment: :( yep... it is strange. the dmesg returns this : [    0.396231] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

Comment: I already have tried to add ath5k and ath9k to the blacklist, but nothing changes...

Comment: I really dislike saying this... but if the dmesg doesnt show anything about why the network isnt being recognised, you might have to download the win xp driver, extract the .inf and use ndiswrapper :(

Comment: So, I've did what you suggested, but don't know why still not working. :(

Comment: that looks like good news - I'm assuming you've got "enable wireless" in network manager do you see any APs in Network Manager?  If you temporarily remove all security from your router can you connect?  What wireless channel are you using? - some countries you can only use a specific range of channels

Comment: this is what is annoying me. It is not showing anyone. And actually besides the fact the commands is showing me that everything seems to be ok, I can't see the card lights yet.

Comment: about your question I have create a wep internal wireless (channel automatic 11) in my macbook and I already have my wife's desktop 10.04 connected to it and sharing my connection. I will bought a router asap :). Now I'm trying to include my PC on this network.

Comment: hmmm ... what is strange is that the latest trace says 32bits but you said you've tried 64bit winxp driver.  The only other suggestion I've got is to download the 32bit version of ubuntu and retry (you should be able to retry all of this via a live-cd i.e. you may not need to actually install this) - googling, looks like ndiswrapper is only successful on 32bit installs and should be used only with 32bit winxp drivers :(

Comment: Yep, when I've tried with XP(32), Vista(32/64), win7(32/64) I got an exception at the ndiswrapper gui. Only when I choose XP(64) it accepted without errors (it seems). :s

Comment: the more distressful is that I DID something (in some configuration file) yesterday that makes the card to wake up (light start to blink)... but it gone when I restarted... after that i think I've installed moreless zillions of times the 11.10 server and desktop :) I will try with the 32 version... but I think this will no bring good news from other stuffs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just confirmed... 
R2x00 package (RT61pci module) doesn't work with 64bits environments.

At least I have tested with Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.10, both server and desktop and I have tried with Debian Squezze 64 too.

They recognize the card, but the driver just don't work.

I have tried to compile it against the 64bit distrib, but didn't work either.

I've installed the 32bits version and the network manager works perfectly, out of box. :(

Comment: well done for perservering on this +1